# "on MY way to school" vs "on THE way to school"

Tags: prepositions, nouns

I just wonder between

> I am on **the** way to [location]

and

> I am on **my** way to [location]

I wonder what the differences are.

Comment: Since you are talking about what "I" is doing, it is only natural to use "my". "on the way" refers to the path, not what you are doing. "*On the way* to school, the bus broke down."

Answer (score 2):

> I am on **the** way to school

has the feeling of being on the route to school in the standard fashion

> I am on **my** way to school

has more a feeling that you are *rushing* or that you may be *focussed* than usual to get to school.

The standard answers to the question

> Are you coming?

are

> I am on **my** way!
>   I'm making **my** way over now!

Comment: What you say is generally true, I think, although it's worth pointing out that these nuances are subtle and most native speakers don't really think about them very much. In other words, if someone asks me, "Where are you?" I can answer with either "I'm on my way" or with "I'm on the way," and everyone knows I'm en route.

Comment: I don't know that I can agree that "*I am on **my** way to school* has more a feeling that you are rushing or that you may be focussed than usual to get to school."  It doesn't imply that to this US English speaker.  "*my* way" just emphasizes that it's my route in particular or that I am the one travelling.

Comment: I think this use of "on *my way*" is different than "I did it *my way*". I agree it is used for emphasis. If you were asked "Are you on **your** way to school?" the answer would be "Yes, I'm on **my** way!" which doesn't necessarily have connotation for a particular or habitual route, but simply you are moving towards school, and also "I'm on **my** way is more often used when one is running behind." may be for emphasis(?)

Comment: I have to laugh a little bit - as an articulate speaker of American English, anyone finding a difference in the two usages is looking at ghosts. There really isn't any. There might be a difference in other English speaking countries, but the two usages are interchangeable in the US.

Comment: For comparison, I would say there is a difference between "You're in **the** way!" and "You're in **my** way!" as well as "Get out of **the** way!" and "Get out of **my** way!"  At the beginning of a journey one might say "We're on **our** way!" but not "We're on **the** way!"

Answer (score 0):

I'm on *my* way to school.   What you're *doing* now, traveling to your school.

I'm on the way to school.   *Where* you are and the path or road you're taking now.

> Where did you meet him?
>   --I met him on the way to school.
>
> When did you meet him?
>   --I met him on my way to school.

**on the way to school** can refer to the road or path that leads to school but school might not be your destination:

> The car-fire is on the way to school. You can't miss it.
>   --I'm on the way to school now, but I don't see it.

Whereas **on *my* way to school** refers to what you're doing at the moment, going to school.

> Sorry, I can't talk now, I'm on my way to school and am running a little late. I have to be on time today.

Answer (score 0):

Not a native speaker, but after consulting all the dictionaries I could find, there are a few things I picked up on.
You'll use both  or  when you mention the destination.

- I can pick you guys up on the way *back*
- I'll drop by his place on my to *the store*

But, in answer to, say, someone asking you if you've set off (when they're waiting for you etc), while you can probably use either, it's more usual to use **I'm on my way**, rather than **I'm on the way** (when not mentioning the destination)

When talking about doing or experiencing something while on your way somewhere, when you DON'T mention the destination, you'll usually use *on the way*, and not *on my way*

- I can fix you sandwich to eat on the way (*on your way* doesn't really sound right, but it would if you added the destination or direction: I can fix you something to eat on your way *there* )

Finally, to be *on your way* can be used in the sense of leaving a place, "get going", as in *"I'd better be on my way- it's getting kind of late"*, *"I should be on my way"* -  *but not on the way*

I'm not by any means sure if I'm right or not, these are just a few observations, so I don't know whether they're anything to go by, but I figured they'd be worth mentioning nonetheless. It seems a lot has to do with whether or not the destination or direction is mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a significant difference between the two. I can't think of a situation where I would automatically prefer one over the other. I think any difference is stylistic - in the tone of what is said. One seems a bit more "personal" - as though one were speaking to a friend. The other seems a bit more formal. They communicate the same action, but colored by who I might be speaking to, and how I want them to perceive me. Even so, the difference, if any, is so small as to be negligible.

Comment: As I replied as a comment to a another post:  
"I have to laugh a little bit - as an articulate (sic native) speaker of American English, anyone finding a difference in the two usages is looking at ghosts. There really isn't any. There might be a difference in other English speaking countries, but the two usages are interchangeable in the US."